# Two Bootstrap Modals freeze Page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the issue, that when I have declared two Bootstrap Modals at the end of my .cshtml-file, opening the first-declared Modal causes a freeze of the whole page.

If I change the order of the two modals, again the first-declared Modal causes the freeze.

Therefore I think it has to do something with the place of declaration.

My general setup is like this (in this order):

**First Modal call:**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Action1", "Action1_AL", "Controller",
                            new { id = x },
                            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "Preview_first_modal", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "Open_first_modal()" },
                            new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-default" })
```

**Second Modal call:**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Action2", "Action2_AL", "Controller",
                            new { id = y },
                            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "Preview_second_modal", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "Open_second_modal()" },
                            new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-default" })
```

**First Modal setup:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="my_first_modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body align-self-center" id="Preview_first_modal">
                @*PartialView*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second Modal setup:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="my_second_modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body align-self-center" id="Preview_second_modal">
                @*PartialView*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Open_first_modal() {
    $('#my_first_modal').modal('show');
}

function Open_second_modal() {
    $('#my_second_modal').modal('show');
}
```

**css-file:**

```
body {
}

th {
    border: solid 1px #ddd !important;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px #ddd !important;
}

table.dataTable.no-footer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
}

body .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
}

.modal {
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-open .modal {
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

In both modals I display a PartialView, which is loaded by the ActionLinks `Action1_AL` and `Action2_AL`.

In this setup clicking the button to call the first modal causes a freeze of the page.

Do you know how I can handle this error? Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Added the .css-file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly went wrong, but replacing the modal properties css by

```
.modal {
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .modal:before {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        content: " ";
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.modal-dialog {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

solved the problem.